# High Voltage OR Gate

Tags: logic-gates

I am currently controlling 120VAC solenoids with panel-mounted switches. Each solenoid controls the air line for a single disk brake. Now I need to incorporate an NI CompactDAQ. My boss has asked that the solenoids can be controlled either by the DAQ's digital control module or the panel-mounted switches we are currently using. The picture below is a simplified diagram of what I want to do. What is the best way to do this?

[image: High Voltage OR Gate]

Comment: I am assuming that the CompacDAQ outputs are un-committed relay contacts. If so, simply parallel the relay contacts with the manual operator (switch).

Comment: @DwayneReid But the switches have a 120VAC supply and the CompactDAQ outputs are 24VDC. How could I have them in parallel with two different voltage sources?

Comment: Is both a 24v relay and 120v relay an option? Their outputs can be paralleled.

Comment: How do you want the either/or to work?  If the panel switch turns on the solenoid, do you expect the DAQ to turn it off?  Easy way (DAQ relay contact in parallel with panel switch)  would require that whoever turns it on has to turn it off.

Comment: You're did not tell us what the outputs were from the PLC. I assumed they were uncommitted relay contacts. That assumption was obviously not the correct.

Comment: Tell your boss that you will provide [this](https://youtu.be/n3wPBcmSb2U) and he/she can program one of the relays to yield the desired results.

Comment: @DwayneReid I'm not sure what you mean by "uncommitted relay contacts". Here is a link to the module we are going to use it's the  [NI-9472](https://www.ni.com/en-us/shop/select/c-series-digital-module?modelId=122224).

Comment: @rdtsc That is what I have been thinking about doing. I wanted to see what other's opinions were as far as what the best solution is.

Comment: @jonk lol perfect.

Comment: @PeterBennett It just needs to follow OR gate logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would not be worth your while retaining the old 120VAC control and attempting to marry that with the NI system.

It would be much easier to discard that and have an integrated 24VDC control/user interface.

The 120VAC solenoids and other outputs could be controlled through 24V relay contacts.

Latched switches for solenoids etc. may be avoided, and 'zero-volt' safety ensured, through the use of momentary pushbutton switches.

Comment: Hi Sneakyp33t, I am looking forward to receive your comments.

Comment: I think this is what I will end up doing. I'll just buy new 24VDC switches and tie the output from the PLC and switches together on the 24VDC side of the relay and connect the solenoids to the 120VAC side of the relay. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Anytime, Sneakyp33t. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Connect N.O. relays with 24 Vdc coils to the output of the PLC. Connect the Normally Open relay contacts in parallel with the panel buttons.

If the panel switches are latching (maintained-contacts), tell us exactly what you need.

Comment: The switches are latching.

Comment: Okay.  That adds another layer of complexity to the project.  You need to modify your original question and describe **EAXTLY** what is required.  Does the PLC have the ability to disable the panel switches?  Or: do the panel switches have another position that selects remote control from the PLC?  Something has to arbitrate what happens when the panel switch is ON and the PLC wants to turn that function OFF.  Please describe fully what it is that you need.

Comment: In the Industrial Oven control panels that we build, the blower switches are three-position: ON, OFF, AUTO.  Similar industrial control panels are similar but with different names: HAND, OFF, AUTO.

Comment: A simple OR gate will work. Each solenoid controls an air line to a large disk break. If a brake is already engaged when the PLC tries to power the solenoid that's not a problem.